# Strange behavior with AXIOS POST

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, axios

I have a simple function to test on my application:

```
        this.$userService.getRestaurantsList(userTemp).then(
            response => {
                console.log(response);
                console.log('FUNCIONOU');
            }
        );
```

Because I getting errors when I make this simple post, and is giving me this:

**Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.**

This is not CORS my server is configured fine with CORS.

When we go deep to getRestaurantsList method I have this:

```
getRestaurantsList(user) {
     return axios.post(configMain.MAIN_URL + this.GET_COMPANY_RESTAURANT_LIST_URL, JSON.stringify(user));
}
```

I want to send data like RAW data with AXIOS but if I use stringify it works the post, but if I use like this

```
getRestaurantsList(user) {
     return axios.post(configMain.MAIN_URL + this.GET_COMPANY_RESTAURANT_LIST_URL, user);
}
```

Only the JSON data it gives me the error you guy see above, and in my API is just returning the data for testing :

This is from LARAVEL API

```
public function getAllRestaurants2(Request $request)
{
    return $this->sendResponse($request->all(), 'Restaurants retrieved successfully');       
}
```

Some update what I'm working on, if I send like this is working:

```
return axios.post(configMain.MAIN_URL + this.GET_COMPANY_RESTAURANT_LIST_URL, null, {
    params: {
        search: user
    }
});
```

Only this approach that is not working:

```
return axios.post(configMain.MAIN_URL + this.GET_COMPANY_RESTAURANT_LIST_URL, user);
```

Here is my interceptor using STRINGFY and working fine log:

```
{
  "url": "url",
  "method": "post",
  "data": "{\"loja\":\"teste\"}",
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  },
  "transformRequest": [
    null
  ],
  "transformResponse": [
    null
  ],
  "timeout": 0,
  "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
  "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
  "maxContentLength": -1,
  "maxBodyLength": -1
}
```

Now the interceptor using the wrong approach:

```
{
  "url": "url",
  "method": "post",
  "data": "{\"id\":\"\",\"name\":\"Anderson Teste\",\"email\":\"teste@email\",\"client_restaurant_id\":11,\"company_id\":1,\"cpf\":\"\",\"phone\":\"81293932921393\",\"locations\":[],\"password\":\"123mudar\"}",
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8"
  },
  "transformRequest": [
    null
  ],
  "transformResponse": [
    null
  ],
  "timeout": 0,
  "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
  "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
  "maxContentLength": -1,
  "maxBodyLength": -1
}
```

Here is my configuration from CORS package :

```
[
    'paths' => ['project/api/*'],
    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
    'exposed_headers' => [],
    'max_age' => 0,
    'supports_credentials' => false,
];
```

What I'm doing wrong that posting like JSON data format is giving me errors?

Comment: Hi Phill, my POST request is working good because if I post with this JSON.stringfy(data), or like this return axios.post(configMain.MAIN_URL + this.GET_COMPANY_RESTAURANT_LIST_URL, null, {
    params: {
        search: user
    }
}); it works fine with no problem, my CORS I use a package in Laravel fruitcake/laravel-cors, I put on my code the console from Interceptor.

Comment: This is driving me crazy and no one is helping I don't know what to do anymore

Comment: I just install a package and everything is working fine, only if I try to send a JSON in a post. I use a package in Laravel fruitcake/laravel-cors. My requests GET e POST is working fine, POST is giving me error only if I send a JSON object but if I send with JSON.stringfy() is working fine.

Comment: Yes, you've already said all that. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64577157/edit) and add details showing **exactly** how you're integrating the `fruitcake/laravel-cors` package in your app. If you've [customised the configuration](https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors#configuration), show exactly what you've done.

Comment: I update my answer and put my config, is the default

Comment: Looks similar to [this issue](https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors/issues/460). Make sure you have the most recent version

Comment: I will try to update to 2.0.3 I have 2.0.0

Comment: Ah, there's the problem. There is an update in 2.0.1 that fixes this issue

Comment: I have laravel 5.8 and this package doesn't allow me to install 2.0.1 how can I force an install from a package?

Comment: You should be able to install 2.0.1. It supports Laravel 5.5+ ~ https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors/blob/v2.0.1/composer.json#L25. Looks like they dropped support for Laravel 5 in 2.0.2 onwards

Answer (score -1):

you will need to make the getRestaurantsList function asynchronous.
try this code.

```
getRestaurantsList(user) async {
     return await axios.post(configMain.MAIN_URL + this.GET_COMPANY_RESTAURANT_LIST_URL, user);
}
```

Comment: okay try to return response from axios
axios.post(configMain.MAIN_URL + this.GET_COMPANY_RESTAURANT_LIST_URL, user).then(response => return response);

Comment: The first function is exactly what I do and is giving me this Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Comment: ok that means the problem is in the server you will need to add the header content-type to Access-Control-Allow-Headers. add this code to your htaccess file in laravel.
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type"

Comment: `getRestaurantsList` was already async because it returned the Promise created by `axios.post()`. Adding `async` / `await` here is completely redundant